# IComparable<T>.CompareTo() return values?

Tags: c#

Just a curious question about the `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` method; I know that the method needs to return positive, negative or zero based upon the comparison, but does it actually matter what I return in the former 2 cases? In other words, does it make a difference if I return +1 or +1000?

Comment: No.. 1, 10, 100, 1000 are the same. The only important thing is the sign (or 0). I suggest against returning `int.MinValue` as an explicit value.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @xanatos - that's really bad advice. Especially as some creative use of the result uses multiplication. This invites overflow. Click the link from @siride and notice the `return 1;`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Anyone that multiplies the result of a `CompareTo` deserves anything that happens to him/her. Or even that adds it. Now then, if you want to play the "obfuscated C# contest", then that is another problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman And just out of curiosity... `((byte)255).CompareTo((byte)1) == 254` on .NET 4.5 (seems to be the same for `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `char`)

Comment: @xanatos `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` returns subtraction result for  `sbyte, short, ushort, char` types, while it returns -1,0 or 1 for types as `int, long, string` and so on. And the reason of that is the return value of the method is `int`. And it will get out of the range if it subtracts values for types like 'Int32', 'Long' and so on. For example, for `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does it make a difference if I return +1 or +1000?

It shouldn't. But caution says it's better to be safe both ways:

- always return -1, 0, +1
- always consume with `< 0`, `> 0`

Comment: In my experience, in many cases, `CompareTo` delegates to another `CompareTo`, where that other `CompareTo` is provided as part of the .NET Framework and can return values other than -1, 0 and 1. I certainly wouldn't recommend something like `int CompareTo(MyObject other) { int result = Id.CompareTo(other.Id); if (result < 0) return -1; if (result > 0) return 1; return 0; }` over `int CompareTo(MyObject other) { return Id.CompareTo(other.Id); }`. (Assuming it makes sense to compare `MyObject`s by looking at the `Id` property.) I read your answer as recommending the former. Is that correct?

Comment: When it's a straight forward chaining I wouldn't write the `if()`s , but rule 1 applies wen you originate or combine any results.

Comment: Even if you combine results, I'd rather write it as something like `int CompareTo(MyObject other) { int result = A.CompareTo(other.A); if (result == 0) result = B.CompareTo(other.B); if (result == 0) result = C.CompareTo(other.C); return result; }`, which does not guarantee a return of -1, 0, +1. It's perfectly valid if you would write it differently, but I don't really see much of a problem with returning other values, I don't see how to keep the rewritten version equally readable, and so I don't really understand your recommendation there.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  I suppose my next question would be, how is the return result actually used in a sorting procedure?

Comment: Depends on that procedure. But a good one would have code like `if (a.CompareTo(b) < 0) ...`

Comment: `IComparable<T>.CompareTo()` returns subtraction result for `sbyte, short, ushort, char` types, while it returns -1,0 or 1 for types as `int, long, string` and so on. And the reason of that is the return value of the method is `int`. And it will get out of the range if it subtracts values for types like 'Int32', 'Long' and so on. For example, for `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue`. I added a detailed explanation in my answer.

Comment: The subtraction result is an optimization, not something you have guarantees on. It could be different in another (version of) the framework.

Comment: @hvd — regarding your first comment, why not use [`Math.Sign(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd3y5wdf(v=vs.110).aspx)? You're effectively reimplementing it.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Fair point, I wouldn't recommend `int CompareTo(MyObject other) { return Math.Sign(Id.CompareTo(other.Id)); }` over `int CompareTo(MyObject other) { return Id.CompareTo(other.Id); }` either. :)

Answer (score 9):

**The answer is that:**

[`IComparable<T>.CompareTo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns ***subtraction result*** for  `sbyte, short, ushort, char` types, while it returns ***-1,0 or 1*** for types as `int`, `long`, `string` and so on.

```
var result = ((byte)10).CompareTo((byte)2); // 8
var result = ((short)1).CompareTo((byte)11); // -10
var result = ((int)10).CompareTo((int)11); // 1 ??
```

**The reason of that:**
First of all, let's look at the signature of the method:

> int CompareTo(    T other )

As you see, the return type is `Int32`.

It is plain as day that the developers want to return the difference of values.
But, the return type of `Int32` subtraction can be less than `Int32.MinValue` or greater than `Int32.MaxValue`.
For example, let's take that:

```
// Return type is less than minimum int value  (-4294967296)
(Int32.MinValue).CompareTo(Int32.MaxValue) 

 // Return type is greater than maximum int value (4294967296)
(Int32.MaxValue).CompareTo(Int32.MinValue)
```

So, they have decided to return subtraction result for types which has "small" value range than the return type of the method which is `Int32` in that case.

At the last, you can look at the implementation of that method in all types from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/):

[Here is the `Int16` implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int16.cs,4f2f28ae4cd2bc79):

```
   public int CompareTo(Int16 value) {
            return m_value - value;
        }
```

[Here is the `Int32` implementation:](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252)

```
public int CompareTo(int value) {
            // Need to use compare because subtraction will wrap
            // to positive for very large neg numbers, etc.
            if (m_value < value) return -1;
            if (m_value > value) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
```

**At the end:**

But, of course in the future they can change the implementation of that code and the recommended way is to compare the result with 1, 0 or -1 always as explained in msdn.

***Less than zero*** (This instance precedes other in the sort order.) 
***Zero*** (This instance occurs in the same position in the sort order as other.)
***Greater than zero*** (This instance follows other in the sort order.)

Comment: This is just the current implementation. You would be wise not to rely on  any specific return value (other than 0) from Compare.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I totally agree with you. But, the reason of this result was interesting to me and I think that it might be interesting for others. So, I have added the reason as answer.